# Mongos takes hours to 'show collections'

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a mongo 2.4.8 cluster. My software dynamically partitions data, and I now have about 30,000 sharded collections. The cluster currently contains only one shard (which is a replica set); it is a cluster to allow easy future expansion.

When I start a new `mongos` process and run `show collections`, it takes it several hours to complete. During this time the `mongos` is unresponsive to all clients (but the cluster is fine). If I never run `show collectoins`, all other operations through the `mongos` work normally.

Eventually `show collections` completes and after that the `mongos` works fine, and running `show collections` again on the same `mongos` returns right away. I only found out there was a problem when I needed to restart a `mongos` for the first time in many months, during which the collection count rose greatly.

Logically, it would seem that data transfer (about collection chunks) from the config servers to the new `mongos` is the bottleneck. But neither side shows high CPU or network activity while this is going on.

Is this known behavior? How can I further investigate the problem?

Comment: Can you state the dimensions of the config servers? Plus, how is the latency between the config servers and between the config servers and the shards?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the `config` database (as seen via `mongos`) is 32MB data, 250MB on disk, 62k objects. All servers are in EC2, in different zones of the same region, so latency should be < 10 ms. The config servers run on small nodes, but they don't have high resource usage, so I didn't try to enlarge them.

Comment: I was referring to the instances' dimensions, but the additional information does not hurt. ;) Very strange, I can not reproduce your problem. The only thing I can think of is that name resolution always runs into a timeout. Can you check how long an ssh login takes from your `mongos` to your config servers, from your config servers to the primary replica and vice versa, respectively?

Comment: They are all in EC2 and use DNS names resolved by EC2 nameservers, I've checked and there's isn't a problem on that end. Besides, it doesn't fit the pattern of taking very long but then succeeding.

Comment: It would perfectly match that pattern as mongos and the config servers usually cache the location of chunks on the shards ( well, actually the shard range for each shard). But they verify this from time to time, iirc, for sure when the config servers start and maybe when the first connection from a mongos is made. So even when there is a single shard, verification can take a while if each request takes a long time to resolve a host name and the name isn't cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the problem to a faulty config server. After replacing it, everything is working fine again.

Details: the bad server didn't respond to queries, after which they were re-sent to other servers. This created an effective latency for each request to the config servers, which was most pronounced in the 'show collections' operation that does at least one roundtrip per collection between mongos and the config servers, and does them all serially.